# Webpack, React & Babel, not rendering DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I finally after hours made my `Webpack`, `React` & `Babel` build setup, but when I try to just run a simple render `Hello World` it doesn't output anything in the DOM.

Here is my code.

```js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And when I watch my bundle.js I can see it imports all the React & ReactDOM I need to run the render.

The test I'm running is from: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html.

Getting this console error: `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.`

Comment: Could you remove the spaces between the < h1 > here? So to <h1> and see if this helps? Are you sure the div-id in your index.html is content?

Comment: Sorry the spaces in tha H1 is made byt the stackoverfly tidy thing ill remove it form the snippet - and yes its my ID from my HTML

Comment: Worst dummy mistake ever yes i get a console error.

`Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.`

Comment: When you are using webpack, look at the "build" folder, and search inside the bundle.js file for "Hello, World". If it's there, check with the Dev Tools if bundle.js is loaded.

Comment: @gruberb - its in the bundle.js file ive made sure of that, issue it now with the console error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bundle.js` is executed when the `content` element isn't yet parsed an created. Just move your `script` element to the **end** of the markup.

Comment: If I hadn't decided to waffle on and give a markup example, I would have beaten you to it :-)

Comment: Thanks man Worked! :) i didn know this. Is this somewhat Webpack specfic?

Edit: ill give you an answer checkmark aswell

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with Webpack actually. It's just the way the DOM and HTML parsing work.

Comment: Scripts are executed immediately after they're parsed.

Comment: Hmm thats wirede normaly i have had all my scripts before my Markup normaly (both angular and react) and have been working. Well know i know this for future refrence thank you and @shennan alot.

Comment: Sometimes it's not important. It depends on the script. In this case, `document.getElementById` gets called when there is no element with id='content' in the DOM yet.

Comment: Okay Makes perfectly sense, so i guess i can use a rule of thumb that i shoudl just include application scripts in the buttom of my Body and Vendor dependencies in the top ?

Comment: Yes, it's safe to do this. Although there might be cases when you want to place a script with some initialization code in the head so that it'd be executed before HTML parsing. E.g. if the server renders the page slowly, you can get some performance gain this way.

Answer (score 3):

Your `bundle.js` file is being loaded before the DOM has had time to load. This means that it won't be able to find your `<div id="content">` when you have asked for it.

Try putting the script loader before the end of the body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When browsers find a `<script>` tag, they pause execution while they download the file. This means that your DOM has only partially rendered when your `bundle.js` script begins executing. So you would have essentially been passing `undefined` to the `ReactDOM.render` method.

If you have not had this issue in the past, perhaps you have been using the `jQuery.ready` event handler, which waits for the DOM to be loaded before executing.